# Passing variables to html from Python

Tags: python, html

I have a function which sends a mail to a user, like this:

```
import os
import smtplib
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage

EMAIL_ADDRESS = email
EMAIL_PASSWORD = password


msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email Title'
msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = ANOTHER_EMAIL_ADDRESS

msg.set_content('Email content')
html = open('email.html', 'r').read()
print(html)
msg.add_alternative(html, subtype='html')


with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

And the html file is like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <h3 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: large;font-weight: bold;">Hey there, {{userEmail}}!
        <h3>


</body>

</html>
```

I want to be able to pass the 'userEmail' variable to the HTML file.
How may I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `email.html` change `{{userEmail}}` to `{userEmail}`. Then you should be able to use [Python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) to add the `userEmail` variable.

```
userEmail = "MyFriend"
html = open('email.html', 'r').read().format(userEmail=userEmail)
print(html)
```